# Complete QGIS Uninstallation to fix TauDEM Issues

Tags: qgis, taudem

I was looking to completely uninstall QGIS 2.18.14 from my laptop as I have managed to do something with the settings that has stopped the TauDEM provider from creating any outputs from any of the processes I have attempted to run.

The steps i have taken are as follows-
- Run QGIS uninstaller
- Deleted QGIS2 folder from C:\Users\me.qgis2
- Run Revo Uninstaller for removing trace files and folders

The problem is that somewhere there is a setting or folder remembering my last working configuration as when i reinstall QGIS the plugins, WMS layers and Panels that I have had opened for my daily work, are still opening as they were before even after a fresh install.

Is there something I am missing to have a fresh install with all the default tools and pathways reset to as they were if I had never had a copy of QGIS on my machine before?

I believe the problem may have arisen when i tried to install a newer version of SAGA GIS onto my machine but i can't be 100% certain as I have only noticed this TauDEM problem over the weekend. No matter what I do it always says the 'The following layers have not been created'. I have removed the newer version of SAGA but it is still not allowing me to create anything using TauDEM provider. the version of TauDEM is 5.3.7 x64 for Windows. I am currently running Windows 10 on my laptop.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem with TauDEM, but uninstalling and re-installing QGIS didn't work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I could not get QGIS completely removed from the laptop. No matter what i did it still remembered settings from the previous install. I ended up doing a complete re installation of windows as the laptop I was using was quite new and didn't contain much information that wasn't already backed up onto my external hard-drive. That fixed my problem and i can get outputs from TauDEm again. It isn't an ideal solution if you are using a work PC but for my personal use it was the only way I could rectify my situation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fix your issues with TauDEM, but you can reset QGIS to default settings from

> Settings menu > Options >  System > QSettings

[image]